# Xamarin.Forms: How to add a NavigationPage XAML class to another XAML class?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

The following code works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainTabbedPage">
  <NavigationPage Title="asdfee">
    <x:Arguments>
      <ContentPage Title="asdf">
        <Label Text="asdfawwer"/>
      </ContentPage>
    </x:Arguments>
  </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

But if I want to have the NavigationPage in a separate XAML file, in a different directory, it doesn't work. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.MainTabbedPage"
             xmlns:layouts="clr-namespace:MyApp.Layouts">

  <layouts:MyNavigationPage Title="asdfee"/>

</TabbedPage>
```

Being **MyNavigationPage.xaml** inside Layouts directory but with **exactly the same code** from the previous code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.Layouts.MyNavigationPage">
  <x:Arguments>
    <ContentPage Title="asdf">
      <Label Text="asdfawwer"/>
    </ContentPage>
  </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
```

When I do it this way, it throws the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: NavigationPage must have a root Page
>   before being used. Either call PushAsync with a valid Page, or pass a
>   Page to the constructor before usage.

I was getting this same error before when all the code was like the in the **first example** and I didn't have the `<x:Arguments>` before the children of **NavigationPage**. So I'm guessing is a problem with the child creation order.

Also if I do the second approach with a **ContentPage**, it works.

Am I doing something wrong or should I fill a bug report?

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Adjust your TabbedPage by adding < TabbedPage.Children > 
Like so: (notice I added an event for CurrentPageChanged)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="MyApp.MainTabbedPage"
        xmlns:layouts="clr-namespace:MyApp.Layouts"
        CurrentPageChanged="TabbedPage_CurrentPageChanged"            
        >

<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="asdfee">
        <x:Arguments>
            <layouts:MyNavigationPage Icon="myIcon"/>
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Your page you are navigating to should be a ContentPage.  Add your Title to your page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Layouts.MyNavigationPage"
         Title="asdf">

    <Label Text="asdfawwer"/>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 2):

@Dpedrinha

This is possible.

> Xamarin.Forms: How to add a NavigationPage XAML class to another XAML class?

[Example for NavigationPage in XAML](https://gist.github.com/Easter1021/c2ed3e4f53c939bd3a2a64c400d682e9)

Comment: it is a interesting of the solutions, isn't it?

Comment: Link no longer working. Is this still available somewhere?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that you can create a NavigationPage in XAML.  I always do it from code:

```
var nav = new NavigationPage(new MyContentXaml());
```

Comment: I don't like this approach as a fix. Either I have everything in C# or all my layout in xaml. And it works in XAML. Although in this case it's having a weird behavior.